# Highcharts - how to get consistent mouseover and mouseout events for columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How to get consistent mouseover and mouseout events for highcharts columns?

The issue can be replicated by hovering the mouse horizontally back and forth along the middle of the chart in this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/looshi/qog3oxg6/20/)

EDIT : 
This issue has been resolved by the below accepted answer.
In addition, I recommend setting tooltip.shared to false,  and plotOptions.column.stickyTracking to false.

```
tooltip: 
  shared: false 
plotOptions:
  column:
    stickyTracking: false # Mouse events will occur on column vs surrounding area
    point:
      events:
        mouseOut: onItemMouseOut
        mouseOver: onItemMouseOver
      states:
        hover:
          enabled: false # Removes default mouse over behavior.
```

In the screenshot, the arrows represent the mouse hovering back and forth along the middle of the chart.  The expected behavior is that the currently hovered column will be full opacity.
[image]

This is how the mouse events are declared in the highcharts options configuration :

```
plotOptions:{
            column:{
                point: {
                  events:  {
                    mouseOut: onItemMouseOut,
                    mouseOver: onItemMouseOver
                    },
                },
                states:{hover:{enabled:false}},
            },
        },
```

These are the mouse event handlers :

```
var onItemMouseOver = function(){
    console.log('mouseover');
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var series = chart.get('series-1');
    var currentItem = this;
    // Reduce opacity of all columns besides currently hovered column.
    for(var i=0; i<series.segments[0].length;i++){
        var segment = series.segments[0][i];
        if(segment!==currentItem){
            segment.graphic.attr({opacity: 0.3});
        }
    }
}

var onItemMouseOut = function(){
    console.log('mouseout');
    var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
    var series = chart.get('series-1');
    var currentItem = this;
    for(var i=0; i<series.segments[0].length;i++){
        var segment = series.segments[0][i];
        segment.graphic.attr({opacity: 1});
    }
}
```

I'm using a custom tooltip style, I had some suspicion the tooltip is interfering with the normal mouse events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about simply setting the opacity of the item you mouse over to `1` along with the other items to `0.3`:

```
if(segment!==currentItem){
    segment.graphic.attr({opacity: 0.3});
} else {
    segment.graphic.attr({opacity: 1});
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/qog3oxg6/21/)

This way the hovered column will be for sure highlighted. In some cases when moving to a new column the item you moved to would still have an opacity of `0.3` causing the seemingly inconsistent behaviour, this means that two `mouseover` events happened rather than a in-between `mouseout`. This can happen when you have mouse events happening nearly the same time and the elements being very close to as each other (or even overlapping).

Comment: Yeah, that should work.  There is some odd behavior though if you mouseover the actual column, then mouse out 1px outside the column.  The mouseout event will fire, but if you then mouseover the column, the mouseover event does not fire again.

Comment: It's related to my other question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33788158/highcharts-restrict-mouseover-area-for-a-column-to-its-own-shape-vs-surroundi  .     It seems like there should be options to explicitly set where the mouse events occur.