# Restrict mouseover area for a column to its own shape vs. surrounding area

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, highcharts

How to restrict the mouseover and mouseout events for a highcharts column so that the events fire when the mouse enters/leaves the actual column vs. the surrounding area ?

The mouseover/mouseout behavior can be seen in this [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/looshi/qog3oxg6/20/).

This is how I'm declaring the mouse events in the highcharts options :

```
   plotOptions:{
        column:{
            point: {
              events:  {
                mouseOut: onItemMouseOut,
                mouseOver: onItemMouseOver
                },
            },
            states:{hover:{enabled:false}},
        },
    },
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to just remove shared: true from tooltip options.

```
// shared: true
```

See [your updated fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nishith/qog3oxg6/22/)

Comment: cool.  Also plotOptions.columns.stickyTracking should be false, right  ?   Which they are by default for columns I think.

Comment: yes , that's right. In an answer 2 days ago I used stickyTracking:false for line chart as its not by-default false.